# python dataframe convert epoch to readable datetime hour minutes seconds as zero

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, epoch

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
period
1651622400000.00000
1651536000000.00000
1651449600000.00000
1651363200000.00000
1651276800000.00000
1651190400000.00000
1651104000000.00000
1651017600000.00000
```

I have converted it into human readable datetime as:

```
df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['period'], unit='ms')
```

and this outputs:

```
2022-04-04 00:00:00
2022-04-05 00:00:00
2022-04-06 00:00:00
2022-04-07 00:00:00
2022-04-08 00:00:00
2022-04-09 00:00:00
2022-04-10 00:00:00
2022-04-11 00:00:00
2022-04-12 00:00:00
```

hours minutes and seconds are turned to 0.

I checked this into https://www.epochconverter.com/ and this gives

```
GMT: Monday, April 4, 2022 12:00:00 AM
Your time zone: Monday, April 4, 2022 5:45:00 AM GMT+05:45
```

How do I get h, m, and s as well?

Comment: seems is added timezone in `https://www.epochconverter.com/ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use `https://www.epochconverter.com/` is added timezone.

If need add timezones to column use [`Series.dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) and then [`Series.dt.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
df['period'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['period'], unit='ms')
                  .dt.tz_localize('GMT')
                  .dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kathmandu'))
print (df)
                     period
0 2022-05-04 05:45:00+05:45
1 2022-05-03 05:45:00+05:45
2 2022-05-02 05:45:00+05:45
3 2022-05-01 05:45:00+05:45
4 2022-04-30 05:45:00+05:45
5 2022-04-29 05:45:00+05:45
6 2022-04-28 05:45:00+05:45
7 2022-04-27 05:45:00+05:45
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code or with pandas. And I don't think the timezone is an issue here either (as the other answer says). April 4, 2022 12:00:00 AM is the exact same time and date as 2022-04-04 00:00:00, just in one case you use AM... You could specify timezones as `jezrael` writes or with `utc=True` (check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)) but I guess that's not your problem.